# In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex -- Cordova build compilation error

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build an app in cordova. Everything was working fine till last few days. But now build is failing continuously.

The error is

`ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings`

`ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex`

I tried all the possible methods mentioned in stackoverflow.
I cross checked all the plugin.xml file and made changes for the app compat version not to use 28. Removed and added platforms several times. Did cleaning the cordova project. Manually edited project.properties. But so far no luck.

Here is my project.properties file.

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-extension/rml-rjfun-libs.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.3=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0
cordova.system.library.8=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
cordova.gradle.include.2=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/rml-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:support-v13:26.+
cordova.system.library.10=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1
cordova.gradle.include.3=phonegap-plugin-push/rml-push.gradle
```

My plugin list

```
cordova-custom-config 2.0.3 "cordova-custom-config"
cordova-plugin-admobpro-firebase 2.29.23 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-apprate 1.1.7 "AppRate"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.5.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.3.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.7 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.5 "cordova-googlemaps-plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 2.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.3.2 "Toast"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.1.7 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.9 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 6.0.8 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.2 "PushPlugin"
```

Please help me. I am stuck with the build.

**Update 1**

build.gradle file dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.+"
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Comment: Could you show your *build.gradle* file *dependencies version* for *com.android.support:support-v4* ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ, Added the build.gradle dependency.

Comment: Did you tried changing *com.android.support:support-v4* version to specific version instead of + *com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0* ? Then try *clean & rebuild* if not working then try *remove platform android* & *add platform android*.

Comment: @JayRathodRJ, Tried the same as you told. Still same error.

Comment: May be this can [*help you*](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/197).

Comment: @JayRathodRJ, Tried all that mentioned in that link. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue related with incompatible new version of support library. Check your plugins folder, find lines with ~ `com.android.support:support-v4:`  and replace with `com.android.support:support-v4:26+`

Comment: I did folder search in my plugins directory and updated the plugin.xml which had the issue. Then I made changes to the project.properties file to ensure nothing is there with `com.android.support:support-v4:+`. But still issue is there.  Is there any chance due to previous `com.android.support:support-v4:+` reference, any particular library got updated in the sdk folder and my app is still referring to that even though I changed project.properties ?

Comment: @SANGEETHKUMARSG Have you tried to remove and add platform to apply changes in your project?

Comment: @autumn-cat, I did that. But no luck.

Comment: Issue resolved, there was some reference in one of plugin for com.android.support:support-v4:. Fixed it and rebuild the app, it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Try add code from https://gist.github.com/caiovncius/8f639420823fd3e75a9ea6e039b11615 into your `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}

configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
       force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
   }
}
```